# SwiftUI View extension restrict where clause lead to crash

Tags: swift, swiftui, crash, extension-methods

I try to write View extension by restrict where clause,code is very simple:

```
struct FooView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("hello world")
        }
    }
}

// only FooView type can invoke standard()
extension View where Self == FooView {
    func standard() -> some View {
        self
            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
    }
}
```

I call standard() like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            FooView()
                .standard()
        }
    }
}
```

But run it will crashed in Xcode Preview! (Xcode 12.2 + MacOS 10.15.7)
Is there something wrong with what I wrote?
Thanks ;)

Comment: Why don't you just extend `FooView` instead of `View`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor you're right!but I just want to know extend from View why not working. ;)

Comment: @hopy any luck with this? am curious to find out as well. I wonder if its because is not a protocol. as the error says something about protocol witness etc..

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure... Maybe I should try it in the latest Xcode 14  ;)